# Autorun program hidden from Task Manager

Tags: boot, task-manager, autorun

Is there are way to Autorun an executable on Windows at system startup, using the registry, or anything else which hides the start entry from the Task Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taskmanager shows all possible ways a program can start with windows. If the program is not listed there, it will not start.

This means that you cannot hide a startup from this list, but you can cloak it. It is possible to have a different program start at startup, and make that program start another program. In that case, the 2nd program is not listed, but the first program is. It can still be traced, but is harder to do. You could make a batch script, place that in shell:startup and the batch script starts one or more programs of your choosing. The task manager's startup tab would only list the script, not what it starts.

Another way that will work, is by letting task scheduler start the program. The downside of this approach is, that it will take a performance hit, and therefor is discouraged.